# What does exit code -1 mean in php's exec method

Tags: php, linux

I am executing the following php code, and the status returned is -1, while output array is empty. What does this mean?

```
$cmd = "sort -T /var/www/html/my_app/protected/runtime/sort// -t '|'  /var/www/html/my_app/protected/runtime/workflow/db-export/filename_1818.txt -o /var/www/html/my_app/protected/runtime/workflow/db-export/filename_1818.txt 2>&1";
exec($cmd, $output, $status);
print_r($output);
echo $status;
```

Comment: It's not from PHP, it's from the `sort` command which you tried to execute.

Comment: Might be, any ideas for what exit code = -1 could mean from sort command?

Comment: I have no idea, it could be the sort command or it could be the bash shell producing that exit code. However, the single quotes around `'|'` looks very strange. If you copy and paste that command into the command line then does it work?

Comment: yes that is working perfectly fine, here '|' is to specify the column separator in the csv file, it is not the linux pipe operator.

Comment: I tried your code and it works well, and i looked at the sort man page and there is no mention of "-1" exit status. I suggest you to try to replace sort by /bin/sort first ?

Comment: What user does PHP run as? If that user does not have access to execute `sort` or if it's environmental variables are not set up properly then that could be causing your issue.

Comment: You can find out the user quickly with `exec('whoami', $output, $status); echo $output;`. This assumes that the PHP user can execute `whoami`